# I'm Going to the Moon!

Tags: pattern, story, outer-space

You and your friends were having lunch during your break in school when suddenly one of your friends shouted **"I'm going to the moon!"**. One by one, he asked your friends what they are going to bring if they are going to join him.

Cathy: I'm going to bring lots of milk because the moon looks like a yummy white chocolate cookie!
Alex: I'm going to bring vegetables then. I'm a vegetarian.
Michael: Eggs. I'm bringing eggs. The moon reminds me of eggs because of its color.
John: -points to the mango he is eating-.
Kate: I'll bring jam then. Max, bring bread please!!! Please!
Max: Okay fine, I'm bringing sourdough bread though.
Yuji: I'm going to bring my favorite udon!

You sat there, ready to munch on your deliciously prepared nachos with jalapeno sauce and cheese, when Russel suddenly asked you.

Russel: How about you then? -while pointing at you-. What would you bring?

You looked confused. You weren't sure of what you are going to answer. You thought carefully and closed your eyes for a good whole minute. After that long minute of thinking, you opened your eyes, smiled and fed yourself with one big piece of nacho.

**Question**: Why didn't you answer anything? Did you figure out the pattern? Or did you just give up?

Comment: Did you know [we are having a topic challenge on](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/fortnightly-topic-challenge-2-outer-space) [tag:outer-space]? I think your question fits. Maybe add the outer-space tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm happy bringing:

> Nachos

Each person is bringing something which

> Begins with the same letter as a planet in order of distance from the sun.
>  Mercury -> milk.
>  Venus -> vegetables
>  Earth -> eggs.
>  Mars -> mango.
>  Jupiter -> jam.
>  Saturn -> sourdough.
>  Uranus -> udon.
>  My planet would be Neptune

Comment: Exactly! Nice going! :)

Comment: @Takeshi so thats why you deleted the first question where you ate pizza. :)

Comment: Yes, I got too excited. XD

Comment: Udon is an unusual enough choice in this context that it might be a bit of a giveaway.  (Nothing wrong with it, it just stands out in this grouping.)  Unfortunately, I can't think of too many western foods that start with a 'U'.  Maybe you could work with the originally proposed name of Herschel, and have the last person eating a hamburger?  That might go the opposite way and be too obscure though...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman How about uncooked cabbage?!

Comment: What about undercut?

Comment: Unshelled shrimp (or w/e) or Urchin

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Upsidedown cake.

Comment: Poor pluto :(, he was suppose to bring Pie to the moon

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza See the second comment for what Russel really brought to the moon ;)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yes, I completely understand where you're coming from. I actually had to search for foods that start with U, but alas, I have found nothing that would not be weird in the bunch, all I see were un'verb' here which sounds bad and may look vague as they may consider the noun rather than the adjective that starts with 'u'. I was left with udon and added a Japanese character to make it look less obvious, but yea. Still obvious, I know. :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Exactly, my original post had 'you' eating a pepperoni pizza but I noticed I left out 'N' for Neptune. I also decided to just exclude Pluto as this may cause a problem as Pluto is not considered a part of the major planets anymore.